# How to create dynamic entry widgets in tkinter based upon user inputs and store input from those entry widgets in a list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am a beginner at python , and in my code I want to create entry widgets based upon user input and then store the inputs in a list , the problem is that the values that the list is storing is of non type I am not able to use the list as well

```
def displayinput():
    r = var.get()

    for x in range(1, r + 1):

        Label_max = Label(master, text="T MAX").grid(row=11 + x,column=4)

        Lbael_min = Label(master, text="T MIN").grid(row=11 + x, column=6)

        list_1.append(Entry(master).grid(row=11+x,column=5))
        list_2.append(Entry(master).grid(row=11+x,column=7))
        x = x + 1
```

Here var is the input from user for the number of entry boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the return value of the grid function is stored which is None in every case.
To be able to process the data of Entry elements, you should create a list of variables and pass as textvariable argument to the Entry instances.

```
def displayinput():
    r = var.get()

    for x in range(1, r + 1):

        Label_max = Label(master, text="T MAX").grid(row=11 + x,column=4)

        Lbael_min = Label(master, text="T MIN").grid(row=11 + x, column=6)

        list_1.append(StringVar())
        list_2.append(StringVar())
        Entry(master, textvariable=list_1[-1]).grid(row=11+x,column=5)
        Entry(master, textvariable=list_2[-1]).grid(row=11+x,column=7)
        x = x + 1
```

Or you can store the Entry instances and fetch their inputs :

```
def displayinput():
    r = var.get()

    for x in range(1, r + 1):

        Label_max = Label(master, text="T MAX").grid(row=11 + x,column=4)

        Lbael_min = Label(master, text="T MIN").grid(row=11 + x, column=6)

        list_1.append(Entry(master))
        list_2.append(Entry(master))
        list_1[-1].grid(row=11+x,column=5)
        list_2[-1].grid(row=11+x,column=7)
        x = x + 1
```